# How to load images in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-template

Hello I am new to angular 2 . I am in a small project , where I have to set images.
This is my app.component.ts

`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
fullImagePath: string;
constructor() {
    this.fullImagePath = '/assets/imges/therealdealportfoliohero.jpg'
  }
ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

`

and the html is 
`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img [src]="fullImagePath">
    </div>
</div>
```

`

but in this process I have to declare all the images in separate variable.but I want to declare an array ,and load all and use them like `

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img [src]="fullImagePath/(myImagename)">
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I got it

`<img id="logo" [src]="fullImagePath + '/logo.png'" alt="Simpla Admin logo" />`

and I don't have to declare as an array.
just

`this.fullImagePath = '/assets/imges';`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `*ngFor` if you want to iterate through an array.
For example, if you have this array of image paths:

```
this.imagePaths = ['image/path/1.png', 'image/path/2.png', 'image/path/3.png']
```

You can do this in your html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div *ngFor="let path of imagePaths">
           <img [src]="path">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to only iterate through an array of image names you can do it this way:

If you get an array with image names while already having a base URL:

```
this.imageUrl = '/assets/images/';
this.images = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png'];
```

You can do it this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div *ngFor="let image of images">
           <img src="{{imageUrl + image}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you haven't set an `imageUrl` property, you can do this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div *ngFor="let image of images">
               <img src="/assets/images/{{image}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your did good ,I appreciate it.But I would like to make something like this ` 

 this.path='./assets/imgs';   <img [src]="path/+imagename">  `

Comment: If you don't want  assets folder you can edit .angular-cli.json and add your folders name as you need. i.e  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "img",
    "favicon.ico"
  ] <img src="/assets/img/{{image}}">   in this case i used img